# Too much [result]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, blocklist-request

The [result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/result) tag does not have any specific purpose. It is used for all kinds of results from return-values, search results and other outcomes. Thus, please remove and blacklist this tag.

Comment: Tag wiki is also awesome: *Possible results include "success", "error", "input", "login", "none"*

Comment: @rene: 42 is missing.

Comment: Suggested title: Remove this tag for a positive [result]

Comment: Help improving the [result].

Comment: Tag is complete useless, but there is 863 questions to review, is it really that harmful that we should put energy into reviewing all of those?

Comment: @PetterFriberg: The powers that be can make the edit silently, without touching all the questions

Comment: Please elaborate on the blacklist request. I can understand the wish to burninate, but blacklisting is reserved for particularly persistent tags, that usually survive multiple burninate attempts. Is that the case?

Comment: @false No, we can't do that. I mean, we can merge or rename the tag without touching all the questions, but that would not be appropriate here.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed as dupe. The old one is *quite* old, and it seems worthwhile to revisit the conversation anew rather than necromancing the original.

Comment: Stack Exchange doesn't have a concept of "necromancing", @feelinferrety. If you want to support the request, then vote and/or discuss it there. Leaving this as a pointer is already sufficient to "reinvigorate" the old request, directing attention to it. Nothing is going to get actioned until it achieves a high level of community support and a moderator gets around to featuring it, as described in [the burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070).